# Sublime Text 3 toggle on/of side bar shortcut

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I want to have a shortcut for showing/hiding the side menu, because I mainly use sublime on a flipped monitor.

I tried this but it doesn't work...

```
[
{"keys": ["ctrl+alt+q"], "command": "show_side_bar"}
]
```

t

Answer (score 1):

The command is actually `toggle_side_bar`.

This can be discovered for any command or action by opening the console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>`</kbd>) and running

```
sublime.log_commands(True)
```

Run whichever commands you wish, and the command names along with any runtime parameters will show up in the console. When you're done, it's usually a good idea to run

```
sublime.log_commands(False)
```

to avoid your console filling up with nonsense, such as every single key you press.

---

By the way, there already is a keyboard shortcut for showing and hiding the side bar: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>. That means hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>, release them, then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>.

Comment: On a side note, running the log command API will show the command name and any of the **relevant argument(s)** associated with the context in which the command was invoked. It may/may not show all of the command arguments.

Comment: @AshwinShenoy that's what I meant. I added in "runtime" to describe the parameters you'll get from `log_commands()`.